# Linking error while embedding Python in C++

Tags: visual-studio, linker-errors

I am trying to embedded Python code into top level C++ application using Visual Studio I am getting linking error LNK2001 as mentioned below,

**Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Initialize**

I have updated the below settings,
Properties->Linker->General->Additional Linrary Directories = C:\Python27\libs\

I have also gone through the document at http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(LNK2001)&rd=true
But it didn't help.
Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time to debug the error, I came to know that the error was because of wrong "solution platform". After changing the solution platform to x64 the error is no more.
But Along with this, make sure to include all the header files @ C:\Python27\include\
and "Additional Library Directory" = C:\Python\libs\

Answer (score 0):

I got it right by changing the platform on which i was building and the installed python platformm to same.

Comment: Details please!  What platform did you use?